# Joining results from one query with another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries.  The first gives me a list of BusinessUnitIds along with a count for each:

```
SELECT   [b].[BusinessUnitId], COUNT([b].[BusinessUnitId]) AS bucount
                        FROM     [dbo].[ComponentTeamBusinessUnit] [b]
                        WHERE    [b].[GlobalClientFiscalYearId] = @GlobalClientFiscalYearId
                        AND      [b].[ComponentTeamId] IN (SELECT items FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@ComponentTeamIds, ','))
                        GROUP BY [b].[BusinessUnitId])
```

I want to take the BusinessUnitIds in this result and join them to a second query which will retrieve the Business Unit Name associated with the BusinessUnitIds. Something like the following:

```
Select [c].Name, [first query result].Count from [dbo].[BusinessUnit] [c]
       INNER JOIN [first query result]
       WHERE [c].BusinessUnitId = [first query result].BusinessUnitId
```

Ultimately, what I want is a listing of Business Names, along with a count of each.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.  Can anyone help?  To do both queries in a single statement would be tops.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a little snippet of the schema so we can see what your working with as a model?

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server.  The second query is pseudo-code.  The first query works.

Comment: you do not need to join based on the result of your 1st query, just do the join, group by `A.BusinessUnitId, B.name`, only if that is not consistent, A and B are alias for the joining tables, could vary

Comment: Can you give an example of this @LONG?

Comment: I don't see why that won't work almost exactly as you've written it if you name the subquery and use an "on" for the join instead of a "where". SELECT c.name, firstquery.count FROM businessunit c inner join ([full text of first query in () brackets]) firstquery on c.businessunitid = firstquery.businessunitid

Comment: @DwightMendoza, check below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exmaple:

```
SELECT   [b].[BusinessUnitId],A.Name, COUNT([b].[BusinessUnitId]) AS bucount
                        FROM     [dbo].[ComponentTeamBusinessUnit] [b]
                        LEFT JOIN NameTable as A
                        ON A.BusinessUnitId = b.BusinessUnitId 
                        WHERE    [b].[GlobalClientFiscalYearId] = @GlobalClientFiscalYearId
                        AND      [b].[ComponentTeamId] IN (SELECT items FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@ComponentTeamIds, ','))
                        GROUP BY [b].[BusinessUnitId],A.Name
```

If tables are One to One, will be neat, if one to many, you will see the result like:

```
id name count
1   A     5
1   B     6
```

And if you want to group `id 1`, to get:

```
id name count
1   A,B  11
```

That you need to use `FOR XML PATH()` together with `STUFF`, or `STRING_SPLIT`, really depends on your real case.

Comment: generally speaking, it will work for most cases, but it depends on the tables relationships, either one to one, or one to many, etc..

Comment: yw yw yw ;) @DwightMendoza